# Encoded dollar sign in form_params causing $top, $skip and $skipToken to be ignored

Tags: php, azure, guzzle

I'm trying to implement pagination when accessing Virtual Machine details through the Azure Resource Graph API. When I use $top and $skip, I still get back all the results as if those options haven't been set. My best guess is that the dollar sign in both variables are being encoded, and that's why the Azure API is ignoring them. When I use PHPStorm's HTTP client, I get the results I'm looking for.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request(
    'POST',
    'https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceGraph/resources?api-version=2019-04-01',
    [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => "Bearer {$authorization_token}",
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'query'         => "where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines' | project id, name, location, resourceGroup, tags, vmId=properties.vmId, vmSize=properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize, networkInterfaces=properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces",
            'options'       => [
                '$top'  => 25,
                '$skip' => 0,
            ],
            'subscriptions' => [
                $subscription_id,
            ]
        ],
    ]
);
```

Is there a better way for me to pass these details into Guzzle so those particular variables aren't encoded?

EDIT:
Adding PHPStorm HTTP Client details:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceGraph/resources?api-version=2019-04-01
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "subscriptions": [
    "<subscription>"
  ],
  "query": "where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines' | project id, name, location, resourceGroup, tags, vmId=properties.vmId, vmSize=properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize, networkInterfaces=properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces",
  "options": {
    "$top": 25,
    "$skip": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: When you use the PHPstorm client, do it send the data as JSON or form-encoded?

Comment: I send it JSON encoded.

Comment: Then don't use [`form_params`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params), use [`json`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json).

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [sammitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064767/sammitch), the corrected code is:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request(
    'POST',
    'https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceGraph/resources?api-version=2019-04-01',
    [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => "Bearer {$authorization_token}",
        ],
        'json' => [
            'query'         => "where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines' | project id, name, location, resourceGroup, tags, vmId=properties.vmId, vmSize=properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize, networkInterfaces=properties.networkProfile.networkInterfaces",
            'options'       => [
                '$top'  => 25,
                '$skip' => 0,
            ],
            'subscriptions' => [
                $subscription_id,
            ]
        ],
    ]
);
```